# Does qemu not permit you to run a VM of the OS you're already running?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu, kernel-panic

This is a reposted version of this question which got closed because it wasn't in Super User:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72706102/why-does-qemu-go-black-when-trying-to-run-a-vm-of-the-os-its-already-running

I'm trying to run a VM in a machine already running Ubuntu, but I don't actually want to VM to be a different OS. So I've downloaded an ISO file with the same version of Ubuntu and I'm trying to run that with qemu (because I'm accessing the machine over SSH and thus can't use a graphical approach). In the link I discuss how the console would just go black, for but a little while I got more output (ending in a kernel panic) with this version of the command:

> sudo qemu-system-x86_64 /home/gamechange/imgs/ubuntu-20.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso -kernel /boot/vmlinuz -nographic -append “root=/dev/sda console=ttyS0”

vmlinuz isn't something I built for this purpose, just the kernel that was already on the machine (which I figure should be fine since I'm trying to run the OS already running there), but my impression is that's not the normal thing and people usually build the bzImage, so I'm not sure if that's the problem. In another question I came across the recommendation to also append a "serial" parameter specifying a file to write to, but no such file got created when I attempted it and afterward I no longer got the kernel panic onscreen either and just the same black screen I had gotten before.

Back when I could get the console to append properly, this was the kernel panic at the end:

> [    1.986377] No filesystem could mount root, tried: [    1.986396]
> ext3 [    1.986765]  ext2 [    1.986900]  ext4 [    1.987038]
> squashfs [    1.987175]  vfat [    1.987337]  fuseblk [    1.987482] [
> 1.987866] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,0) [    1.988685] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not
> tainted 5.4.0-120-generic #136-Ubuntu [    1.989171] Hardware name:
> QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS 1.13.0-1ubuntu1.1
> 04/01/2014 [    1.990000] Call Trace: [    1.991345]
> dump_stack+0x6d/0x8b [    1.991677]  panic+0x101/0x2e3 [    1.991933]
> mount_block_root+0x2c5/0x2e8 [    1.992225]  mount_root+0x38/0x3a [
> 1.992459]  prepare_namespace+0x13f/0x194 [    1.992739]  kernel_init_freeable+0x23f/0x263 [    1.993050]  ? rest_init+0xb0/0xb0
> [    1.993291]  kernel_init+0xe/0x110 [    1.993534]
> ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40 [    1.994488] Kernel Offset: 0x21c00000 from
> 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range:
> 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff) [    1.995424] ---[ end Kernel
> panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on
> unknown-block(8,0) ]---

Comment: You're trying to boot the ISO with a foreign kernel and without its initramfs.

Comment: What makes a kernel "foreign"? It's for the same version of ubuntu. If I look for linux images I can find ISOs, but no kernels to go along with them. I don't know what initramfs is, but I had attempted to use initrd.img as the kernel instead of vmlinuz and that didn't work.